# WooCommerce redirect payment to another website

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I have a WooCommerce website that is not currently able to accept credit card payments, but I have another one that is. Is it possible to redirect the user on checkout to the other url, simply carry over the cart total to be processed (maybe $50), then send the user back to the main page? I would imagine that it's similar to making a custom gateway.

Comment: The browser will notify the user that he/she is being redirected. Is that what you want?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte That should be fine for this purpose